# git comand (with grep) in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to make a git command in powershell.

In the shell i used a "grep" function in the command:

```
git branch -r --merged | grep -v HEAD
```

My powershell script looks like:

```
$Params = @(
 "branch",
 "-r",
 "--merged"
)
& git $Params
```

How can I implement the grep function in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `-Notmatch` with `Select-String`:

```
& git $Params | Select-String -NotMatch "HEAD"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 git $Params | Select-String "HEAD"
```

For more information refer [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7)

Comment: You need to add switch `-Notmatch` because `grep -v` does not match

Comment: Yeah, For that reason  i have pasted the link for various options that can be used